# Spring properties file set null to property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

Currently I have a few property files in my `src/main/resources` folder:

```
- application.properties
- application-dev.properties
- application-test.properties
```

Now, when I specify a profile, it loads both that profile's specific file and the general `application.properties`, overwriting everything with the former.

However, when my application is deployed in production, no profile is passed, so `application.properties` **must** be my production file.

That's fine because I can overwrite everything in the profile specific ones. There is one problem, however; on production, I now need to set:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/appname
```

When I add that to `application.properties`, every profile also inherits that, and then, when I run dev server or a test, it gives me this error:

> Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

Because I indeed don't use this JNDI stuff on my own environments; I use the following properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:url
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
```

My problem is: I cannot overwrite this property for my life. If I add any of these on the env specific files, it will be ignored and the error persists:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name= # empty string, does nothing
spring.datasource.jndi-name=<null> # read somewhere it meant null, doesn't work
spring.datasource.jndi-name=${inexistentProp} # I though it might return null, but gives an error
```

So, what can I do? I think of several solutions:

- A way to set a property value as proper null or undefined in a spring property file (since empty doesn't do the trick)
- A way to change the commonly inherited property file to something else (I tried @PropertySource, but it only add more options, always falling back to application.properties eventually)
- Disable JNDI altogether via properties file, despite the former property (I tried `spring.jndi.ignore=true` as per [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5419), but to no avail)

But either I don't know how or they don't work.

Comment: Why not just use profile `prod` in production?

Comment: I cannot change the production environment, and it doesn't specify any profiles when the app is run.

Comment: How do you run your Spring Boot app? As a program or as a Servlet? I.e. how do you specify a profile? There are many ways to do it.

Comment: When I run it myself I use gradle and I can pass `-Pprofile=something`, but for deploying I just provide a war to the company that's responsible for deploying and there is no way to change this behavior.

Comment: If someone comes here for the *actual answer to the initial question* (setting a `null` value to a properties file entry), try `#{null}` - works as long as you have `spring-expressions` dependency, I believe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot documentation, [24.4 Profile-specific Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties):

> In addition to `application.properties` files, profile-specific properties can also be defined by using the following naming convention: `application-{profile}.properties`. The `Environment` has a set of default profiles (by default, `[default]`) that are used if no active profiles are set. In other words, if no profiles are explicitly activated, then properties from `application-default.properties` are loaded.

[25.1 Adding Active Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html):

> The `spring.profiles.include` property can be used to unconditionally add active profiles.

So, create a `application-default.properties` file with the following property:

```
spring.profiles.include=prod
```

Now move the `spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/appname` property from the `application.properties` file to the `application-prod.properties` file.

When you run code with a specific profile, the `prod` profile will not be used, and `spring.datasource.jndi-name` will be undefined.

When you run code in production, where no profile is specified, the `prod` profile is included by default, and `spring.datasource.jndi-name` will be defined.

---

You can of course just put the production properties in the `application-default.properties` itself, but the above approach makes it more clear what you're doing.

It also makes it easier if you end up with multiple profiles. E.g. you have `prod` vs `dev` vs `test`. But what if you have independent set of profiles such as `foo` vs `bar`, and that default production environment should be `prod,foo`? Allowing alternate production environment to use `prod,bar`, and each can be tested separately (`test,foo` and `test,bar`).

By using the `default` profile to only include other profiles, without otherwise define any properties, you can now manually mix and match profiles, as needed.

Comment: I am running the main application class and it doesnt load application-default, what am I doing wrong

Comment: @KalpeshSoni *"if **no profiles are explicitly activated**, then properties from `application-default.properties` are loaded"*. Conclusion: If `application-default.properties` is not loaded, then you explicitly activated a profile. If you want `default` to *also* be activated, explicitly specify it too.